# How to configure php runtime in lambda for wordpress application?

Tags: php, aws-lambda, runtime, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I have created a cloudformation template for deploying wordpress application using Serverless Application Model.It is serverless so we have lambda and apigateway.So in lambda we don't have a built-in php runtime and it shows a runtime error while sending request So that I have taken (arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:534081306603:layer:php-82:33) this ARN from official bref platform and add layers to my lambda function with this arn to add the runtime dependencies for php.But it shows the error as cannot open shared object file.I have attached the attached the cloudformation template and error screenshots.So I need a solution,what are the possible ways are there to configure php runtime.

ERROR:/opt/bin/php: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The Cloudformation code is

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: WordPress on AWS Lambda!
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Parameters:
  VpcSecurityGroupIds:
    Type: 'List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>'
    Default: 'sg-53af6735'
  VpcSubnetIds:
    Type: 'List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>'
    Default: 'subnet-0dcd7a44,subnet-a8757ef0,subnet-b19c01d6'
  StageName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'Prod'
  CloudFrontPriceClass:
    Type: String
    Default: 'PriceClass_200'

Resources:
  LambaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-phpserver
      Description: WordPress Webserver
      CodeUri: xxxxxxxxxxxx
      Runtime: provided
      Handler: handler.php
      MemorySize: 1344
      Timeout: 30
      Tracing: Active
      Layers:
        # - arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:887080169480:layer:php73:2
        - arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:209497400698:layer:php-73:80
      
      Environment:
        Variables:
          S3_UPLOADS_BUCKET: !Ref assetsS3

      Policies:
        - VPCAccessPolicy: {}
        - S3FullAccessPolicy:
            BucketName: !Ref assetsS3

      Events:
        apiRoot:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: '/'
            Method: ANY
            RestApiId: !Ref restapi

        api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: '/{proxy+}'
            Method: ANY
            RestApiId: !Ref restapi

      # Comment this out to run in public mode.
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds: !Ref VpcSecurityGroupIds
        SubnetIds: !Ref VpcSubnetIds

  restapi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    DeletionPolicy: "Retain"
    Properties:
      StageName: !Ref StageName
      EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL

      # Accept binary uploads.
      BinaryMediaTypes:
        - "*~1*"

  cloudfront:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
          - Id: LambaFunction
            DomainName: !Join
              - ''
              - - !Ref restapi
                - '.execute-api.'
                - !Ref AWS::Region
                - '.amazonaws.com'
            CustomOriginConfig:
              HTTPPort: 80
              HTTPSPort: 443
              OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
            OriginPath: !Join ['', ['/', !Ref StageName]]
          
          - Id: Assets
            DomainName: !Join
              - ""
              - - !Ref assetsS3
                - ".s3-"
                - !Ref AWS::Region
                - ".amazonaws.com"
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity: !Join [ '', [ 'origin-access-identity/cloudfront/', !Ref cfOriginAccessIdentity ]]

        Enabled: 'true'
        IPV6Enabled: 'true'
        HttpVersion: 'http2'

        PriceClass: !Ref CloudFrontPriceClass
        
        CustomErrorResponses:
          - ErrorCode: 404
            ErrorCachingMinTTL: 0

        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          AllowedMethods:
            - DELETE
            - GET
            - HEAD
            - OPTIONS
            - PATCH
            - POST
            - PUT
          ## The origin id defined above
          TargetOriginId: LambaFunction
          Compress: 'true'
          ## Defining if and how the QueryString and Cookies are forwarded to the origin which in this case is S3
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: 'true'
            Cookies:
              Forward: whitelist
              WhitelistedNames:
                - 'comment_author_*'
                - 'wordpress_*'
                - 'wp-settings-*'

          MinTTL: 0
          DefaultTTL: 0
          MaxTTL: 31536000

          ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https

        CacheBehaviors:
          - PathPattern: "*.jpg"
            AllowedMethods:
              - GET
              - HEAD
              - OPTIONS
            DefaultTTL: 300
            ForwardedValues:
              QueryString: 'true'
              Cookies:
                Forward: 'none'
            TargetOriginId: Assets
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https

          - PathPattern: "*.png"
            AllowedMethods:
              - GET
              - HEAD
              - OPTIONS
            DefaultTTL: 300
            ForwardedValues:
              QueryString: 'true'
              Cookies:
                Forward: 'none'
            TargetOriginId: Assets
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
          
          - PathPattern: "*.jpeg"
            AllowedMethods:
              - GET
              - HEAD
              - OPTIONS
            DefaultTTL: 300
            ForwardedValues:
              QueryString: 'true'
              Cookies:
                Forward: 'none'
            TargetOriginId: Assets
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https

          - PathPattern: "*.gif"
            AllowedMethods:
              - GET
              - HEAD
              - OPTIONS
            DefaultTTL: 300
            ForwardedValues:
              QueryString: 'true'
              Cookies:
                Forward: 'none'
            TargetOriginId: Assets
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https

          - PathPattern: "*.css"
            AllowedMethods:
              - GET
              - HEAD
              - OPTIONS
            DefaultTTL: 300
            ForwardedValues:
              QueryString: 'true'
              Cookies:
                Forward: 'none'
            TargetOriginId: Assets
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https

          - PathPattern: "*.js"
            AllowedMethods:
              - GET
              - HEAD
              - OPTIONS
            DefaultTTL: 300
            ForwardedValues:
              QueryString: 'true'
              Cookies:
                Forward: 'none'
            TargetOriginId: Assets
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https

          - PathPattern: "/wp-admin/*"
            AllowedMethods:
              - DELETE
              - GET
              - HEAD
              - OPTIONS
              - PATCH
              - POST
              - PUT
            ## The origin id defined above
            TargetOriginId: LambaFunction
            Compress: 'true'
            ## Defining if and how the QueryString and Cookies are forwarded to the origin which in this case is S3
            ForwardedValues:
              QueryString: 'true'
              Headers:
                - "User-Agent"
              Cookies:
                Forward: whitelist
                WhitelistedNames:
                  - 'comment_author_*'
                  - 'wordpress_*'
                  - 'wp-settings-*'

            MinTTL: 0
            DefaultTTL: 0
            MaxTTL: 31536000

            ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https

  assetsS3:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  
  assetsS3BucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref assetsS3
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Sid: CloudFrontOrigin
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              CanonicalUser: !GetAtt cfOriginAccessIdentity.S3CanonicalUserId
            Action:
              - s3:GetObject
            Resource: !Join
              - ''
              - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                - !Ref assetsS3
                - '/*'

  cfOriginAccessIdentity:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
    Properties:
      CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
        Comment: The Origin Access Identity to allow CloudFront to serve static files from the assets bucket (WordPress on Lambda)

Outputs:
  RestApiDomainName:
    Value: !Join
      - ''
      - - !Ref restapi
        - '.execute-api.'
        - !Ref AWS::Region
        - '.amazonaws.com'
  
  CloudFrontDistributionId:
    Value: !Ref cloudfront

  CloudFrontDistributionDomainName:
    Value: !GetAtt cloudfront.DomainName
  
  AssetsBucketName:
    Value: !Ref assetsS3
```

[Click on to see the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhxHc.png)

Comment: Have you got any solution ?
I was also trying with the bref layer for wordpress and it is not working.
I setup a serverless wordpress using Teraform.
But the php version is old.

Comment: I refered to this blog: https://keita.blog/2020/06/29/wordpress-on-aws-lambda-efs-edition/